# How to auto-detect and wire classes which extends from specific type?

Tags: java, spring, ioc-container

Spring supports to auto-detect classes using annotation @Component and <component-scan>, however, @Component is not @Inherited.

I have tried to create a custom inheritable annotation:

```
@Component
@Inherited
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface MyInheritableComponent {}
```

Unfortunately, @MyInheritableComponent doesn't work.

Any idea?

**EDIT**

File my/package/Injectable.java:

```
@MyInheritableComponent
public class Injectable {}
```

File my/package/Foo.java:

```
public class Foo extends Injectable {}
```

And the component-scan is defined as:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package" />
```

In the above example, Foo is not auto-detected.

My intention is, hide @Component annotation from some specific classes.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What's the use-case?

Comment: How looks your Spring xml compnent-scan tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to absence of `@Inherited` on `@Component` `<context:component-scan>` with default filters doesn't respect `@Inherited` on your custom annotations.

However, if you add a custom filter for your annotation, it would work as expected:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package">
    <context:include-filter type = "annotation" expression = "MyInheritableComponent" />
</context:component-scan>
```